# Modify each row of a CSV via powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a bunch of CSV files that contain data on files from various machines.  It includes info such as the file hash - SHA1, MD5 etc.

Headers
****MD5,SHA-1,SHA-256****

Sample data 
**ecfc9af8d1a6e16223e1b17ea732fa08
,1db05a7a663a0de3b4913bf57f55e81d2b7e3663,bf74e48e2f14dcba257473fccec3e512c7283335610205e3b84cb16449e86335**

My challenge is how to append 0x to every SHA-1 entry in the CSV file.  I have tried several things but nothing seemed to work.  Another mini problem I would like to overcome is that once I re-export the data back to CSV the data has double quotes added to each file hash.  Normally this isn't a problem but in this case I want to take these file hashes and bounce them off of a SQL DB.  This is why I need to add 0x to each entry to make it compatible with the existing hash DB.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Import-Csv will get you some of the way:

```
Import-Csv .\samplehash.csv -Header MD5,SHA1,SHA256
```

produces the output like this:

```
MD5                                                     SHA1                                                    SHA256                                                
---                                                     -----                                                   -------                                               
ecfc9af8d1a6e16223e1b17ea732fa08                        1db05a7a663a0de3b4913bf57f55e81d2b7e3663                bf74e48e2f14dcba257473fccec3e512c7283335610205e3b84...
ecfc9af8d1a6e16223e1b17ea732fa08                        1db05a7a663a0de3b4913bf57f55e81d2b7e3663                bf74e48e2f14dcba257473fccec3e512c7283335610205e3b84...
```

Now pipe the result into a foreach (%) to create SQL string.

```
Import-Csv .\samplehash.csv -Header MD5,SHA1,SHA256 | 
%{ "insert into hashes(md5,sha1,sha256) values('0x{0}','0x{1}','0x{2}')" -f $_.MD5,$_.SHA1,$_.SHA256 }
```

Now use those strings with Invoke-SqlCmd or similar (depending on db system) to insert the rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Both answers have helped me get much further.  I think I have the hang of it but I have one issue.  When I use the above it generates a SHA1 column with a title of 0xSHA1.  This becomes a problem when I try to assign it to a variable before using in my SQL query. This is what it would look like $SHA1=$line.0xSHA1 but to powershell throws a parsing error when I  try to us it.  I tried quotes but I am pretty sure that isn't supposed to work.  Thanks again to all that responded.

Comment: Okay...that was dumb.  I figured out how to do it.  when I reimport use the -header.  Thanks for the help.  $data = Import-Csv C:\Data\AUTORUNS-DATA\Final\FinTest.csv -Header "machinename","imagepath","sha1"

Answer (score 0):

Import your CSV with Import-CSV:

```
$csv = Import-CSV import.csv;
```

Append 0x to every SHA-1:

```
$csv | %{ $_.{SHA-1} += '0x' };
```

Make a header row with the property names of the first data row:

```
$header = @(,$csv[0].psobject.properties | %{,$_.name});
```

Turn the entries into a value array instead of row objects:

```
$data = ($csv | %{,($_.psobject.properties | select -expand value)});
```

Manually output a basic CSV with no quoted fields:

```
( $header+$data | %{ $_ -join ',' }) -join "`r`n" | sc import.csv
```